# getting error when trying to change asp.net label values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net website. I want to change the label values in a JavaScript function.

Here is my code,

```
<td id="m1" runat"server" onclick = "createChart_Jan"></td>
<asp:Label ID="lblGeneral" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
```

JavaScript,

```
function createChart_Jan() {
   var month = 1;
   var d = new Date();
   var month_current = d.getMonth() + 1;
   if(month > month_current)
   {
      document.getElementbyId("lblGeneral").innerHTML = "0";
   }
   else
   {
      document.getElementbyId("lblGeneral").innerHTML = "500";
   }
}
```

But I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error when I click on td element.

Any idea on what is wrong with above code?

Comment: Since you don't tell us what line throws that error and you have numerous syntactical and typographical errors (each which would give its own error), this question should be closed for the above stated reason. To have it re-opened, please take a moment and fix your typographical errors and make sure to invoke the method correctly; and then report any errors to us once you do that.

Answer (score 2):

You have few errors -

1. Calling function from click should be `onclick="createChart_Jan();"`
2. If you want to call server-side control's ID from client-side, you want to use `lblGeneral.ClientID`.
3. You have typo in **getElementById** *(getElementbyId is incorrect)*

### Fix

```
<td  id="m1" runat="server" onclick="createChart_Jan();">test</td>
<asp:Label ID="lblGeneral" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
<script>
    function createChart_Jan() {
        var month = 1;
        var d = new Date();
        var month_current = d.getMonth() + 1;
        if (month > month_current) {
            document.getElementById("<%= lblGeneral.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "0";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("<%= lblGeneral.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "500";
        }
    }
</script>
```

### How to debug

You can use browser's debugger to debug the JavaScript. For example, [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPgCQ.png).

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the td also have to be in a table?  Mine was yelling at me until I nested it in <table><tr></tr></table>

Comment: You are correct. I changed it to **div** while I was testing. [ScreenShot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aPgCQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You Should try to get it by the ClientID and not by the serverID

something like:

```
document.getElementById('<%= lblGeneral.ClientID %>')
```